# No module named 'cv2' : enivroment issue?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda3

Hey guys I really need help here. When I load up my conda prompt in base env and use `pip list` it shows that `opencv-python` is installed.

[image]

however when i `import cv2` on my jupyter notebook i get an error which says - **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'**

I then used `os.sys.path` and it turns out that all the directories point to my conda env named 'py37' and not my base env which i have used to launch the jupyter notebook. How do i make sure all the pip installed packages are available on my base env?